# Why isn't this function to scrape a table with Selenium working as intended?

Tags: python, function, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the table on [this website](https://results.decisiondeskhq.com/2020/primary/colorado/president) with Selenium (you need to make a quick account and login to see it). To get the first column, I use the following code, which works:

```
first_column = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='top-line-table']//tbody//td[2]")
for i in first_column:
    print(i.text)
```

Prints:

```
Bernie Sanders
Joe Biden
Michael Bloomberg
Elizabeth Warren
```

However, when I try making it into a function that I can input the column I want into, it only returns the first value, "Bernie Sanders". Here's my code to define, call, and print the function:

```
def scrape_column (column):
raw = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='top-line-table']//tbody//td[{column}]")
for ii in raw:
        return[ii.text]

candidates = scrape_column("2")
print(candidates)
```

I don't know why it only returns the first value, I've tried a lot of things and it still doesn't work. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when you `return` the lifecycle of your function ends. It has returned a value and that's it. If you want to get all candidate names as list, do something like this:

```py
def scrape_column (column):
    names = []
    raw = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='top-line-table']//tbody//td[{column}]")
    for ii in raw:
        names.append(ii.text)
    return names

candidates = scrape_column("2")
print('\n'.join(candidates))
```

Look up `join`, it is a pretty neat stuff.